# Local Report vs Server report in ASP .Net Report viewer control

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

In one of the  ASP .Net site we are currently working we have a bulk load of SSRS reports. We have forms authentication for the site and reports have already been created and deployed in the report server. We are having so many problems with authentication when we set the report viewer control to access the server report.

I just want to know what are the advantages or disadvantages of using Local report vs Server Report

Thanks,

Raja

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1- client report don't need to report server for rendering. (advantage)

2- you must make a server report by creating a report server project in BIDS but client reports must create in VS.

3- server reports use stored procedure or text script as data provider but client reports use dataset or xml datasource for this.

4- server reports use report server for rendering of the report but for client reports this work done at report viewer control.

5- client reports don't need SSRS installation but server reports need that.

6- for working with server reports you must deploy reports but in client reports you don't need this work.

7- for enterprise projects, it is better that you use server report but in other projects client reports are better.

Comment: Awesome....and to add to that....if we use client reports no need to really work on the authentication process.

Comment: in local report you lose the ability to export to some formats

Comment: Quick question, is it possible to have the LOCAL rdlc report to work in the load balanced environment? for example, is it possible to have pagination in RDLC HTML-format report? If so, how would the pagination work in load balanced environment?

Comment: Beautifully answered !