# SQL Reporting 2008. Local vs. Server. (Telerik reporting? )

Tags: sql, reporting-services, telerik

I am trying to understand when we should use one over the other.

From my understanding the local mode means you just bind data to a ReportViewer server control and it renders it as a report.

The server version seem to be the same except it also comes with a Report Manager site and using a SQL DB.

I am thinking that using the server version (how we do it now) is overkill for a site with a few reports that are really just RDL views of the HTML form.. (hardly using any features)

Is there more to the difference between using server vs. local. Are they the same thing from the code point of view?

Any good reason to use Telerik reporting over SSRS local mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered to this question before. please see the below link:

[Local Report vs Server report in ASP .Net Report viewer control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427543/local-report-vs-server-report-in-asp-net-report-viewer-control/2438017#2438017)

maybe can help you.